# Storing an index list with MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL/PHP performance related question.

I need to store an index list associated with each record in a table. Each list contains 1000 indices. I need to be able to quickly access any index value in the list associated to a given record. I am not sure about the best way to go. I've thought of the following ways and would like your input on them:

1. Store the list in a string as a comma separated value list or using JSON. Probably terrible performance since I need to extract the whole list out of the DB to PHP only to retrieve a single value. Parsing the string won't exactly be fast either... I can store a number of expanded lists in a Least Rencently Used cache on the PHP side to reduce load.
2. Make a list table with 1001 columns that will store the list and its primary key. I'm not sure how costly this is regarding storage? This also feels like abusing the system. And then, what if I need to store 100000 indices?
3. Only store with SQL the name of the binary file containing my indices and perform a fopen(); fseek(); fread(); fclose() cycle for each access? Not sure how the system filesystem cache will react to that. If it goes badly then there are many solutions available to adress the issues... but that's sounds a bit overkill no?

What do you think of that?

Comment: Option one would seriously violate the rules of database normalization, so that one's out the window :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a good old one-to-many relationship?

```
records
-------
id     int
record ...

indices
-------
record_id int
index     varchar
```

Then:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM records
 LEFT JOIN indices
        ON records.id = indices.record_id
     WHERE indices.index = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution is to create another table, with one row per (record, index), and add a MySQL Index to allow fast search

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_list` (
  `IDrecord` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `IDrecord` (`IDrecord`)
)
```

Change the `item`'s type according to your needs - I used `int` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical solution would be to put each value in it's own tuple. Adding a MYSQL index to each tuple will enable the DBMS to quickly ascertain the value, and should improve performance.

The reasons we're not going with your other answers are as follows:

**Option 1**

Storing multiple values in one MYSQL cell is a violation of the first stage of database normalisation. You can read up on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

**Option 3**

This has heavy reliance on other files. You want to localize your data storage as much as possible, to make it easier to maintain in the future.